# Spring RestTemplate POST with Google Translate API

Tags: java, spring, google-translate, resttemplate

I'm using [Google Translate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest) with Spring RestTemplate in my application and it works fine until I use GET http request. However if I heve large piece of data the service will return 414 error (Request-URI Too Large).

So I decided to use POST (according to the [note](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest#WorkingResults)).

And here is my code:

```
String content = "q=Hello";
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "GET");
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(content, headers);
String response = new RestTemplate.postForObject(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/" +
    "v2?key=<my_key>&source=en&target=ru", request, String.class);
```

The service returns error 400 bad request and I have no idea why. I have successfully created similar code using jQuery so I know this way should work.
Please help me to fix the problem.

Comment: Just a guess, can you try using MultiValueMap as body for HttpEntity

Answer (score 2):

I think the way you form URI is incorrect and thats why you get 400. Looking at the google translate API documentation, it looks like they expect 'q' as URI query parameter. Also you seem to be doing a POST request for a GET. From [google translate API docs](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest)

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&source=en&target=de&q=Hello%20world
```

Try this,

```
Map<String, String> queryParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
queryParameters.put("key","my_key_here");
queryParameters.put("source","en");
queryParameters.put("target","ru");
queryParameters.put("q","Hello World");

String url =  "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/" +
    "v2?key={key}&source={source}&target={target}&q={q}";

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "GET");
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(null, headers);

RestTemplate restclient = new RestTemplate();
String response=restclient.getForObject(url,request,String.class,queryParameters);
```